# Hide dock icon of new window in air

Tags: apache-flex, air, window, flex4.5, dock

I am working in Flex 4.6 AIR application in which i open a mx:window. when we open that window 
the respective dock icon will display in the taskbar, I want to hide this dock icon of window but not the application, How can i achieve it.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: How to you open the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Window.type = NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;
This will not show the dock icon for new window.